# How does (DataFrame - Groupby) match rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I can't figure out how (DataFrame - Groupby) works.

Specifically, given the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['usera',1,100],['usera',5,130],['userc',1,100],['userd',5,100]])
df.columns = ['id','date','sum']


    id  date    sum
0   usera   1   100
1   usera   5   130
2   userc   1   100
3   userd   5   100
```

Passing the below code returns:

```
df['shift'] = df['date']-df.groupby(['id'])['date'].shift(1)

    id  date    sum shift
0   usera   1   100 
1   usera   5   130 4.0
2   userc   1   100 
3   userd   5   100
```

How did Python know that I meant for it to match by id column?
It doesn't even appear in `df['date']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us dissect the command `df['shift'] = df['date']-df.groupby(['id'])['date'].shift(1)`.

1. `df['shift']` appends a new column "shift" in the dataframe.
2. `df['date']` returns **Series** using **date** column from the dataframe.

```py
    0    1
    1    5
    2    1
    3    5
    Name: date, dtype: int64
```

3. `df.groupby(['id'])['date'].shift(1)` **groupby(['id'])** creates a groupby object.
   From that groupby object selecting date column and shifting one (previous) value using `shift(1)`.  By the way, this also a **Series**.

```py
df.groupby(['id'])['date'].shift(1)
```

```
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    NaN
3    NaN
Name: date, dtype: float64
```

4. The Series obtained from step 3 is subtracted (element-wise) with the Series obtained from Step 2.  The result is assigned to the ***df['shift']*** column.

```py
df['date']-df.groupby(['id'])['date'].shift(1)
```

```
0    NaN
1    4.0
2    NaN
3    NaN
Name: date, dtype: float64
```

Comment: That makes sense. 
I thought groupby will truncate duplicated ids. No magic here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly knowing what you are trying, but `groupby()` method is usuful if you have several same objects in a column (like you `usera`) and you want to calculate for example the `sum()`, `mean()`, find `max()` etc. of all columns or just one specific column.

e.g. `df.groupby(['id'])['sum'].sum()` groups you `usera` and just select the `sum` column and build the sum over all `usera`. So it is 230. If you would use `.mean()` it would output 115 etc. And it also does it for all other unique id in your `id` column. In the example from above it outputs one column with just three rows (user a-c).

Greetz, miGa